# How to update HttpClient base address at runtime in ASP.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microservices, httpclient

I created several microservices using the ASP.net core API

One of these microservices returns the exact address of the other microservices

How to update the address of any of these microservices without restarting if the address is changed

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddHttpClient("MainMicroservice", x =>
        {
            x.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://mainmicroservice.com");
        });
        services.AddHttpClient("Microservice1", x =>
        {
            x.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://microservice1.com");
        });
        services.AddHttpClient("Microservice2", x =>
        {
            x.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://microservice2.com");
        });
        services.AddHttpClient("Microservice3", x =>
        {
            x.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://microservice3.com");
        });
    }
}
```

```
public class Test
{
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _client;

    public Test(IHttpClientFactory client)
    {
        _client = client;
    }

    public async Task<string> Test()
    {
        var repeat = false;

        do
        {
            try
            {
                return await _client
                    .CreateClient("Microservice1")
                    .GetStringAsync("Test")
                    .ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException e) when (e.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            {
                var newAddress = await _client
                    .CreateClient("MainMicroservice")
                    .GetStringAsync("Microservice1")
                    .ConfigureAwait(false);

                //todo change address of microservice1

                repeat = true;
            }
        } while (repeat);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't assign base address, give address that the time of calling GET,POST, PUT

Comment: Is there a problem in terms of performance?

Comment: It sounds like the first service is really a *configuration* source. You can add it as a [custom configuration provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/custom-configuration-provider) and use the URLs it provides in your HttpClient registration.

Comment: OTOH what you ask is what DNS does. If you can control your DNS domain, you can use ALIAS records to create well-known service names that get redirected to specific servers. This way, all that's needed to direct traffic to a different server is a change to the ALIAS

Comment: @Mehdi no there no performance issue included but make sure you have only 1 httpclient instance. If you create mutiple instances then it will lead to performance impact

Comment: A quick solution will be to store these addresses on a json file and fetch them from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are building a microservice-based solution sooner or later (rather sooner) you will encounter a situation when one service needs to talk to another. In order to do this caller must know the exact location of a target microservice in a network, they operate in.

You must somehow provide an **IP address** and **port** where the target microservice listens for requests. You can do it using configuration files or environment variables, but this approach has some drawbacks and limitations.

1. First is that you have to **maintain and properly deploy
   configuration files** for all your environments: local development,
   test, pre-production, and production. Forgetting to update any of
   these configurations when adding a new service or moving an existing
   one to a different node will result in errors discovered at runtime.
2. Second, the more important issue is that it works only in a **static
   environment**, meaning you cannot **dynamically add/remove nodes**,
   therefore you won’t be able to dynamically scale your system. The
   ability to scale and deploy given microservice autonomously is one
   of the key advantages of microservice-based architecture, and we do
   not want to lose this ability.

Therefore we need to introduce **service discovery**. Service discovery is a mechanism that allows services to find each other's network location. There are many possible implementations of this pattern.

We have two types of service discovery: client-side and server-side which you can find a good NuGet package to handle in ASP.NET projects.

Comment: But, If you want to implement the scenario that you mentioned in the question, I think you shouldn't hard code the addresses, instead, you can read data from cache(like Redis or etc). Then whenever the addresses changed, you just need to invalidate the cache value and set a new value into the cache.

Comment: Or use Kubernetes with DNS, and access services by their name directly.

Comment: @Riwen Kubernetes isn't needed to use DNS. What you describe is the job of DNS ALIAS records

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Not saying it's needed. Makes the whole thing so simple, though.

Comment: I think he means we can assign a name to our containers and every docker container can call each other with that name. Kubernetes and Swarm docker can make it easier.